# How to improve this code - sum of fibonacci

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a faster version of this code?

```
def perimeter(n):
    a = [1, 1]
    for i in range(n-1):
        a.append(a[i+1]+a[i])
    return 4*sum(a)
```

I tried to solve some tasks on codewars but there is an error:

> Process was terminated. It took longer than 6000ms to complete

Comment: That isn't an error, per se. It just means your solution was too slow.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  Besides I guess they call your function multiple times, so you do compute your `a` multiple times, which is not necessary.

Comment: there are many ways to speed that up! e.g.  you can use the [matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) of the fibonacci numbers with [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist What about using memoization or any of dynamic programming solutions? Or even better stlll I found that there is a formula for doing this, you just need binet's formula.

Comment: If all you want is sum, why are you storing in a list. Just keep track of sum

Comment: @Anony-mouse you are right, if the idea is to really get a list of all the numbers, meomization is perfectly well suited. if you just want to get `F(n)` and do not care about intermediate results, the variant described above will be much faster (for reasonably big `n`).

Comment: @sam2090 Because the sum is of previous terms.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist  apparently sum has a better formula `F(m+2) - F(n+2) - 2`, where `m` is upper bound and `n` is lower bound. In his case `F(m+2)`. I have an issue with how he approaches it in a particular way.

Comment: @PeterWood I understand that but what I meant was something similar to the answer provided. No need to insert and then call `sum` on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a formula for the sum of fibonacci numbers (ask on http://math.stackexchange.com for that) your solution should be about as fast as it gets. Using the matrix form shouldn't help much since you have to do exponentiation.

However you could avoid memory allocation by first using `xrange` instead of `range` (you're using python2). And also not storing the numbers in an ever growing array:

```
def perimeter(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    s = a+b

    for i in xrange(n-1):
        a, b = b, a+b
        s+=b

    return 4*s
```

The formula solution (using that sum of fibonacci numbers up to F(j) is F(j+2)-2) would be:

```
def perimeter(n)
    if n == 0:
       return 8 # a special case where you add the two first fibonacci numbers anyway.
    n = n+3

    phi = (math.sqrt(5)-1)/2

    return 4*int(round((phi**n - (-phi)**(-n))/math.sqrt(5)))-4
```

Be careful though with this last solution as you eventually get rounding errors that makes you miss the Fibonacci numbers.

To solve the accuracy problem we could use formal expressions of the form `a+b*sqrt(5)`. For simplicity I encapsulate these in a class:

```
class Golden:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Golden( self.a*other.a + 5*self.b*other.b,
                       self.a*other.b + self.b*other.a )

    def __pow__(self, n):
        if n == 1:
            return self

        if n % 2 == 0:
            return (self * self) ** (n/2)
        return self * (self * self) ** ((n-1)/2)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Golden(self.a + other.a, self.b+other.b)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Golden(self.a - other.a, self.b-other.b)

def perimeter3(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 8

    n = n+3

    phi = Golden(1,1)
    psi = Golden(1,-1)

    fn = (phi**n - psi**n)

    assert fn.a == 0

    return 4*(fn.b / (2 ** n)-1)
```

This has the slight disadvantage that it computes powers iteratively, but the number of steps that's needed to do that is not n, but rather log(n) which should give it an edge over the first solution anyway (the disadvantage over the middle is only relevant until accuracy makes the middle solution fail - which is only for small n's).

Comment: for really big numbers of `n` you may run into trouble with float accuracy. note that you will only need the `sqrt(5)` part of `(phi**n - (-phi)**(-n)`. representing `2*phi = 1 + sqrt(5) = (1, 1)` (and writing squaring `(a, b)^2 = (a**2 + 5*b**2, 2*a*b)` and multiplication with `2*phi` as `2*phi*(a,b) = (a+5*b,  a+b)`) you could carry out the exponentiation in the integers and assert that the integer part cancels out.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes, the second solution only works up to and including n=67 here. I mentioned that problem with it. There's room for improvement as you suggested.

Comment: If accuracy were a problem, you could use the [**`decimal`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: @skyking oh, you implemented it! nice. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can generate fibonacci pairs:

```
def fibonacci_pairs(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield a, b
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Then:

```
>>> sum(b for a, b in fibonacci_pairs(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can notice a mathematical fact. Let's `a0, a1, a2 ...` are fibonacci numbers. You want to calculate this statement:

```
a0 + a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an = Sn
```

On the other hand, an = a{n-1} + a{n-2}:

```
Sn = 2*a{n-1} + 2*a{n-2} + a{n-3} + ... + a1 + a0 = (2*a{n-1} + 2*a{n-2} + 2*a{n-3} + ... + 2*a1 + 2*a0) - (a{n-3} + ... + a1 + a0) = 2*S{n-1} - S{n-3}
```

In other words, we've got a recursive statement for the sum:

```
Sn = 2*S{n-1} - S{n-3}
```

Using python we can write such function:

```
cache = {}
def S(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    if n <= 2:
        return n
    else:
        r = 2 * S(n - 1) - S(n - 3)
        cache[n] = r
        return r

def perimeter(n):
    return 4 * S(n)

print S(1000) # it prints 113796925398360272257523782552224175572745930353730513145086634176691092536145985470146129334641866902783673042322088625863396052888690096969577173696370562180400527049497109023054114771394568040040412172632375
```